# How to set an img src tag when loading a random image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am loading random images from an array to a HTML document and that is working fine. The problem is on inspecting the page when it is live it's not updating the src. Is there a way to do this as I'm not having much luck with it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var randomImages= new Array ("images/A.png", "images/B.png","images/C.png");

var randomNumber = Math.floor((randomImages.length)*Math.random());

$('.image').prop('src',randomImages[randomNumber]);
var images = (randomImages[randomNumber]).attr(src);
alert(images);});
```

Above is the random image loading function.

```
<img class="image" id="A" src="" alt="#"></br>
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Tried `$('.image').attr('src',randomImages[randomNumber]);
` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use random function which generate random number which generate all image

```
$('.image').each(function() {

  var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20 + 1),
    img = $(this);

  img.attr('src', 'images/' + num + '.jpg');
  img.attr('alt', 'Src: ' + img.attr('src'));

});
```

or if you want to use array then use this code which generate

```
$('.image').attr('src',randomImages[randomNumber]);
```

Comment: Thanks this is a great alternative method. The src is still blank most of the time even though the image changes. Any advice on that?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('.image').attr('src',randomImages[randomNumber]);

// Extra

var images = (randomImages[randomNumber]).attr(src);

alert(images);
```